# how to simulate ios app in windows using xamarin visual studio 2015

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, macos, xamarin

I am trying to simulate an iOS app on my windows machine using visual studio 2015(Xamarin installed). My windows machine is connected to a mac agent. When I simulate the app in the windows machine the simulator opens in the mac. Can any one tell me how to simulate the app on my windows machine.

Comment: @piyush: How does your edit make "proper understanding"? As far as I can tell, it is simply vandalism. Please do not use code formatting for random English sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VNC to remote into the mac to show the simulator. That is what Xamarin dev's do at Evolve.

Unfortunately, that is your only option at the moment.

Comment: iOS Remoting @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895341/how-to-use-xamarins-ios-remoting-simulator/36895457#36895457

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iOS remote simulator. To use this feature you must update Xamarin and turn on remote simulator in Tools->Options->Xamarin->iOS.

You still need a mac for this feature.

Comment: The simulator gets downloaded but i am not able to install it, when I try to install a pop up appears and gets vanished faster than it appeared. I am using windows 10 and visual studio 2015.

Comment: As of yesterdays update, this is now in stable version and works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the iOS application, you must need MAC machine. Using Windows machine with Xamarin Studio, you can develop iOS application. But to run it on device or simulator, you need Mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these solutions to remotely see the mac window:

- Apple Remote Desktop
- TeamViewer !
- Chrome Remote Desktop
- VNC Client. Activate screen sharing:

[image]

Comment: If i use one of the above mentioned, If suppose mac has two users and one is active , will it get logged out.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem please follow these steps assuming your windows machine is connected to a mac agent:

- Download and install the "Remoted iOS Simulator (for Windows)":

  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/
- Go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings:

  **Tick the checkbox "Remote Simulator to Windows"**
- Click in Build -> Configuration Manager:

  **Find your iOS project in the list and make sure the Platform is "iPhoneSimulator"**
- In your solution explorer right click in your iOS project and go to "Properties":

  **In the tab "iOS Build" find the section "Linker Options" and select the Linker behavior to "Link all assemblies" and Save**
- In your solution explorer right click in your iOS project again and click "Clean" and after that click "Rebuild"
- Set the Visual Studio to run in Debug Mode and select "iPhone 5s iOS 9.3" click in option to launch the iPhone Simulator.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remote iOS simulator is only available on enterprise

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

```
Remoted iOS Simulator requires a Visual Studio Enterprise license
```