# iOS Simulator with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I've installed iOS Simulator for Windows (it's still in preview).
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

I followed the instructions but nothing happens. I expected when I launch the application to iOS (and select a device) a window with the simulator has opened. In my case Visual Studio is Ready and the app seems started (you can see to).

[image: Visual Studio is started but nothing happends]

I followed the advice from @SushiHangover on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895341/how-to-use-xamarins-ios-remoting-simulator). In my TaskManager there is Xamarin.Simulator process running but still nothing happens.

[image: TaskManager with Xamarin.Simulator]

Any advice? Thank you in advcance.

Comment: Did you "Make sure Visual Studio has connected to your Mac at least once before starting the remoted iOS Simulator"?

Comment: Yes, I always checked that

Comment: It would probably a good idea if you gave the results of all the checks you performed (and the actions you took) based on the linked post's check-list / steps, including versions on both the Mac and Windows hosts, any relevant logs, etc.

Comment: iOS simulator for Windows is still in preview I recommend you to file a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll do what you advice me